# Printing Unicode + digit as Unicode

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    char[] msg;
    int code;
    int i;
    String newMsg;

    msg = getMsg(); // Read the message from keyboard
    code = getCode();

    System.out.println("Code : "+code);
    for (i=0; i<msg.length; i++){
        System.out.println(msg[i]);
        System.out.println(Character.toString((char)msg[i]));
        newMsg = ( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(msg[i] + code  | 0x10000).substring(1));
        System.out.println (String.valueOf(msg[i] + code ));
        System.out.println (newMsg);
}

public static int getCode(){
    int code=0;
    System.out.print("Input Code: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    return input.nextInt();
}

public static char[] getMsg(){
    String myMessage;
    System.out.print("Input Message: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    myMessage = input.nextLine();// Read a line of message
    return myMessage.toCharArray();
}
```

my output is the following:

Input Message: a
Input Code: 1
Code : 1
a
a
98
\u0062

I am trying to add CODE in that case 1 to the a and print b, but I can only add it to the unicode or ascii, but I cant go back to b from there.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic addition `+` of a value of type `char` here `'a'` and a value of type `int` here 1 produces a value of type `int` which here contains the (Unicode) character code for `'b'` but is not *type* `char`. To get a value of type `char`, use a cast `(char)(msg[i]+code)`.